# Only First Bootstrap 5 tabs scrolling to top on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, swiper.js

I have a HTML webpage with multiple BS5 Nav Tabs in it. First BS5 Nav Tab are not working and all other Tabs working smoothly (same codes for all BS5). On click of first BS5 Nav Tab page scroll to top of the page with address changes from "..../index.html" to "..../index.html#".

This problem is in all other HTML pages which has BS5 Tabs, Only the First Tab is not working and scrolling to top. Im using Bootstrap 5 and Swiper JS.

I have tried replacing "href" with "data-target" in nav-items, But still the problem exist

This is my Code

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="m-4">
                <h5>Heading</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-target="#tab11" class="nav-link active text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-target="#tab12" class="nav-link text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-target="#tab13" class="nav-link text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-target="#tab14" class="nav-link text-decoration-none text-dark" data-bs-toggle="tab">Tab4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab11">
                        some Bootstrap Card with Swiper JS
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="tab12">
                        some Bootstrap Card with Swiper JS
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab13">
                        some Bootstrap Card with Swiper JS
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab14">
                        some Bootstrap Card with Swiper JS
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must replace the `data-target` attribute by `href` in the `nav-link` elements.

I've tested it in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/adriana-hern-ndez-regueiro/pen/QWVgJBr?editors=1010) and it works.

Comment: I tried changing data-target with href, still onclick scroll to top page

Comment: Check if the Bootstrap javascript is correctly loading in the page. You can see it in Network tab of Chrome Inspector. Also check my codepen that has your code working

Comment: Javascript is loading properly since other BS5 nav tab in the same page is working properly. Of Total 6 x BS5 Nav Tab only first NavTab is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a good way to handle this but there is a simple way to make this problem go away.
you can click on the second tab via javascript when your page load and then click on the first tab to make that active.
it solves the problem but it is not a good way .

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var element = document.querySelector('.nav-item:nth-child(2) a');
        var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window
        });
        element.dispatchEvent(event);

        var element = document.querySelector('.nav-item:nth-child(1) a');
        var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window
        });
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
```